# I lost the properties of my datatable when try to do a filter in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm working with datatables and filters with primefaces.I've a datatable with two columns, the first is the name of a entity the second is a radiobuton to select the entity.

When I've the datatable whitout filter this looks like:

[image]

So, when I try to apply the filter, I get the following "thing":

[image]

My datatable lost the properties the table, I can't see the headers , I can't  see the field to filter, I just see the name of the entity and the radiobutton.

This is the html  code of my datatable:

```xhtml
<p:dataTable id="tabla-oficinas"
     value="#{listadoRDController.oficinas}"
     var="oficina"
     style="width:40%;  margin: 40px;"
     rowKey="#{oficina.codOficina}"
     selection="#{listadoRDController.oficinaSeleccionada}"
     filteredValue="#{listadoRDController.oficinasFiltradas}"
 >
     <p:column style="text-align: center;" 
               id="nombre-oficina"                                       
               headerText="#{i18n['oficina']}"
               filterPosition="top"
               filterBy="descripcion"
               >
               <h:outputText value="#{oficina.descripcion}"/>
     </p:column>

     <p:column style="text-align: center;
               width:20%;"  selectionMode="single" 
            headerText="#{i18n['seleccione']}" />
    </p:dataTable>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the controller:

```java
public class ListadoRDController implements Serializable{
   private Oficina oficinaSeleccionada;
   private List<Oficina> oficinasFiltradas
   private List<Oficina> oficina;
   /**
    *Some process
    */
   ....
   //getter's and setter's

}
```

An this is the Bean Oficina:

```java
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "oficina")
 @XmlRootElement
 @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Oficina.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Oficina o"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Oficina.findByCodOficina", query = "SELECT o FROM Oficina o  WHERE o.codOficina = :codOficina"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Oficina.findByDescripcion", query = "SELECT o FROM Oficina o  WHERE o.descripcion = :descripcion")    
 })
 public class Oficina implements Serializable,Comparable<Oficina> {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "codOficina")
    private Collection<EstadisticoRD> estadisticoRDCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "codOficina", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OficinaCertificacion> oficinaCertificacionList;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "codOficina")
    private String codOficina;

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;
 }
```

So, can anyone help me?

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you testing it with? Which PF version? Is your `dataTable` wrapped into a form?

Comment: Hi, **Browser's**: firefox,chrome,  **PF**:4.0, and  I use the dataTable wrapped into a form.

Comment: Could you provide an entire [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I mean, some code which can be copy-paste and executed in order to replay the problem. Just create a basic bean with some predefined data (no DAO dependencies) and post it. What happens if you remove your `style` attributes?

Comment: If I remove the `style` attributes, nothing  happens.

Comment: From your provided code, Hibernate annotations and queries are unuseful. Just: embed your `Oficina` class in `ListadoRDController` in order to have everything in one class. Create a couple of instances of `Oficina` in the constructor and add them to the list. Keep in mind I don't have your database, I just have a testing environment with JSF installed. You have to provide people just one bean and one xhtml which, copy pasted in their enviroments, will work. The ideal thing is to minimize your code as much as possible. Bring facilities for people to help you!